# Blender Fluids - Domain Problems

Tags: blender

In blender, I'm testing out the fluid simulation stuff - but whenever I tell an object to be a domain it just turns into the fluid I main previously.

- Edit: I'm using the latest version of Blender. (2.70)

Comment: Which Blender version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain settings will be using the same cache directory that was used for your earlier fluid simulation. There is no harm leaving the old cache in place as it will be overwritten when you perform another bake. You can either bake using the new settings or delete the cache folder.

The cache folder used is shown at the bottom of the [domain settings panel](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Fluid/Domain#Baking). The default would be `/tmp/`

Comment: Thank you, deleting all the files in the cache folder fixed it.